# Is there a simpler way to do a one-line try without catch?

Tags: javascript

When I do something like this:

```
let resolved = null;
try {
    resolved = require.resolve(modulePath)
} catch (e) {

}
```

I am wondering if there's a shorter syntax something like:

```
let resolved = null;
try resolved = require.resolve(modulePath)
```

Is there any way to forgive this line without opening up a catch block?

There's something like this but I'm looking for something more natural:

```
function t (fn, def) {
    let resolved = def;
    try {
        resolved = fn()
    } catch (e) {

    }
    return resolved;
}
```

Comment: Nope. You have to have the catch block.

Comment: You could potentially make a method that all it does is executes a callback in the try catch block, but then you've added a secondary method and added the creation of a callback to give it.

Comment: I would just put the catch part all on one line (`} catch (e) { }`), maybe even the `try` on the same line since it's obvious what it does.

Comment: `function t(fn, def) { try { return fn(); } catch (e) { return def; } }`

Answer (score 5):

No; it's intentional that JavaScript `try`-blocks must have either `catch` or `finally`. From https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/try...catch#Description:

> The `try` statement consists of a `try` block, which contains one or more statements. `{}` must always be used, even for single statements. At least one `catch` clause, or a `finally` clause, must be present.

(And note that `try { ... } finally { }`, with no `catch`, does the *opposite* of what you want: you want *everything* to be caught and swallowed, whereas `try { ... } finally { }` doesn't catch *anything*.)

---

In your case, I think the best way to write it is:

```
let resolved;
try {
    resolved = require.resolve(modulePath);
} catch (e) {
    resolved = null;
}
```

which makes clear that `resolved == null` is the error-case.

(Better yet — add some logic to make sure that the exception you've caught is really the one you're expecting. You probably don't want to silently swallow exceptions that result from unintended bugs!)

Answer (score 2):

> Is there any way to forgive this line without opening up a catch
>   block?

Yes, if you implement a `finally` clause.
Other than that, **no**.
A try is always accompanied by **either a `catch` or a `finally`**.

Answer (score 0):

As other answerers have already pointed out, you either need to provide `catch` or `finally`.

BTW, what's wrong with implementing a high-order function?

```js
const valueOrNull = f => {
  try {
    return f ()
  } catch (e) {
    return null
  }
}

const output1 = valueOrNull (() => { throw Error () })
const output2 = valueOrNull (() => "hello world")

console.log ('output1', output1)
console.log ('output2', output2)
```